# create eslint rule based on content from several files

Tags: eslint, processor, rule

In my project I have app.js file and functions.json file.
The app.js file contains some javascript logic and functions.js file contains a simple array with names of valid functions that can be used in app.js.

I need to create an eslint rule validating that all functions listed in functions.js file are used in app.js. In case that not all of the functions are used or some other function is used (not from the list), i need to report an error.

Should i create a processor for function.json to get its content ?
Or maybe i need to use fs module and get the function.json content before my rule runs on app.js file ?
Any other ideas ?

Regards,
Slavik.

Comment: The functions names are dynamic and not known, that is why i need to create a custom rule.